An IL variable is not available at the current native IP. (0x80131304). The error code is CORDBG_E_IL_VAR_NOT_AVAILABLE, or 0x80131304
When I used debug, I found that all the parameters were wrong: An IL variable is not available at the current native IP. (0x80131304).The error code is CORDBG_E_IL_VAR_NOT_AVAILABLE, or 0x80131304.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Please give me some suggestions.

You should mention what tool you're using to debug this C# code; it doesn't look like Visual Studio or VSCode. Rider perhaps?

You are trying to debug this code.  It is part of the .NET framework, not your code.  And it is optimized, which makes debugging difficult.  Making variables disappear is a very strong optimizer goal.  The debugger you are using isn't that smooth about it.  Do focus on debugging your own code, nothing much useful to see in code you cannot change and doesn't have a bug.

Yes, using Rider
